# Limiting add-on installs to User Prefs directory only

Tags: add-on

I'm looking at how we might set up a studio Blender environment.  I'm setting BLENDER_USER_SCRIPTS in the launch environment, pointing to our global Blender area, call it \ourserver\ourblender\scripts.  This bypasses the normal USER scripts location in %APPDATA%.

If users install an add-on through Preferences-Add-ons->Install... it installs into our global scripts\addons directory, which is undesirable.  But the install pane has a "Target Path" popup, which in addition to the "Default" value has a "User Prefs" value which installs the add-on to the additional "File Paths->Data->Scripts" local location the user may have specified, which would be acceptable.  Is there any way at startup to remove the "Default" option from that popup, or freeze the popup to "User Prefs", or otherwise prevent saving to the "Default" location?

I'm trying this in our startup code:

```
newtarget = EnumProperty(
        name="Target Path",
        items=(
            ('PREFS', "User Prefs", ""),
        ),
    )
cls = bpy.types.PREFERENCES_OT_addon_install
bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
cls.__annotations__['target'] = newtarget
bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
```

This unregisters Blender's addon_install operator, tweaks its 'target' annotation to remove the unwanted 'DEFAULT' option, then reregisters the class.  It's a hack, but a relatively clean hack, and superficially seems to work.  But any alternatives or suggestions would be welcome.